# Phonegap, textarea will not accept input

Tags: android, jquery, ios, cordova

This is such a Noob Gingrich question, pretty sure I am missing something simple.

Is there a trick to getting a textarea to work on mobile devices? By work I mean accept text from the softkeyboard.

I've got a mobile app on phonegapbuild. on one page there is a div that contains a textbox and a textarea. When deployed to an android or IOS device, the textbox works just as expected, but when you tap into the textarea, it receives focus just fine, and the keyboard pops up, but nothing you type gets entered into the textarea.

```
    <div id="drawerDetails">
            <div id="drawerTitleWrapper" >
                <input type="text" id="drawerTitle" />
            </div>
            <div id="drawerBodyWrapper" >
                <textarea id="drawerBody" cols="50" rows="20" ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>            
        <div class="submit">
            <div id="newButton"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="close" data-bind="tap: $data.closeDrawer">
             <img src="content/images/Close_CCCCCC.png" />
         </div>
```

Hopefully I am missing something easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check that you are not preventing text selection on form elements?  Make sure that `-webkit-user-select: none;` is not being applied to your textareas.