# Cannot get the value of textarea, Jquery Mobile Apache Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have a similar problem like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737115/phonegap-textarea-will-not-accept-input) and I can't get the text typed of the textarea.

```
<div data-role="content">       
    <textarea id="message-area" name="message-area" placeholder="Put your comment"></textarea>

    <input id="test" type="text" />
    <a id="btn-save" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left">Guardar</a>
</div>
```

When I try to get the text typed with the below jquery snippet I get a null value but if I did with an input element it works. I'm a little confused someone have any idea?

Update

I fix my problem copy the code snippet below based on in this [post](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-text.html) of the jquery mobile demo.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="textarea">Textarea:</label>
  <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

I'm still wondering with this, but this works fine and the other no.

```
 console.log($('#message-area').val());
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Try using `$(document).ready`.

Comment: The instance of the element was created but when I try to get the value typed return a null value. Also if I harcoded a sample text inside a tag still return null.

Comment: At what moment are you calling `console.log`? Because it works pretty well: http://jsfiddle.net/f7fneqx8/

Comment: well should try and fetch the value of the textarea ( using .val() or text()) when some event happens as LcSalazar told...if you try to get its value when the script or not dom ready  you'll get null only...because everytime a page loads textarea is empty...

Comment: The div wich wrapper the textarea are inside `<div id="create-comment" data-role="page" is="page">` and it was load in the start up of the application.