# keyboard not comes up on textarea insight an bootstrap modal window at an HTML5/cordova app

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, modal-dialog, textarea

I have an HTML5 application using cordova to run on an android mobile phone.
This works fine.

Then, I changed the application. I use angluarJS as basic framework and bootstrap to build layout and small animations.

The `textarea`  still works fine. 
In the next step, I moved the `textarea` insight a form, that looks like this:

```
<form  novalidate ng-submit="sendeForm()">
    <div class="container">   
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" >
               <textarea style="width:100%" ng-model="form.msg"  name="news" autofocus>

               </textarea>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="nr" ng-model="form.nr" >{{form.nr}}
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="send">
    <input class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()" value="cancel">
</form>
```

This form is stored in `views/_annotateForm.html` and hidden, until the users tap on a button.
In this case, a bootstrap modal window opens, using that code:

```
   $scope.open = function() {
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'views/_annotateForm.html',
        controller: 'messageSendCtrl',
        size: 'lg',
      });
```

then ... the form appears, but when I tap the `textarea`, no keyboard comes up.

The problem only occurs, if the form is loaded as a view insight the modal window. There is no problem, if the form is part of the main page.

Btw: I know, there are other questions on SO to the topic "keyboard not shown", like this: [Phonegap, textarea will not accept input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737115/phonegap-textarea-will-not-accept-input)  But all of those questions does not fit this case. Removeing `-webkit-user-select`  does not change anything.

Comment: Does the cursor still move into the modal?

Comment: @jollarvia yes, if I tap into the textarea, the cursor is shown.

Comment: @825K Yes, but I had no idea, how. The problem is not present, after using an different version of cordova an angular-js